# Accurately recording both voice and engine sound

Tags: recording, car

I have just bought a ZOOM H5 in an effort to make my videos a bit less amateur.

I have a project in mind which requires me to be talking in a (loud convertable sports) car whilst driving.

SO There are 2 distinct parts to this:

- How can I record the exhaust/engine sound accurately? (placement and type of mic(s), will the onboard YX mic be adequate?)
- How can I simultaneously record my voice clearly? (lapel mic?)

(The ZOOM H5 has an onboard XY mic, and 2x XLR inputs)

Comment: In a convertible with the top down? In my opinion, it can't be done. Even a Zeppelin and a dead cat can only do so much. A lapel mic is worth a shot. If I were in your shoes I would try to get the best possible production audio just as a guide track for looping it (ADR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noise cancellation techniques typically involve two microphones placed closely together, where the one you don't talk into is phase inverted. The sound that hits both microphones equally is then cancelled out. There are special build noise [cancellation microphones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-canceling_microphone) that does this for you, like Olympus ME-52W (Lavalier "clip-on") or the Coles 4104B Lip Microhpone (Stand). The Olympus is probably what you're after.

Or you can make the setup yourself with a preferably matched set of microphones - perhaps not "Lemmy Style", but I'm sure you get the idea (just make sure to invert one signal before combining - this can be done by flipping hot and cold in one of the XLR connectors on the cable):

[image: lemmy cancellation mic]

As for the engine sound - the cancellation mic setup will take up one input in your Zoom. For the other you can probably get away with any decent quality wind shielded mic.

Comment: There are several test videos of that ME-52W  - I think it looks rather promising, here is one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-NKbZMSqaU However several of the videos found on youtube is without speech - i.e. the try to capture the engine, for which this mic is probably the worst choice as it cancels out ambient sounds (the "engine sound" is all over the place).